# How to prevent refreshing the state values when a file input is given in formik

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await, state, formik

I'm making a React (TypeScript) component where `formik` handles user inputs, including both text and file fields.

The problem that I'm having right now is that the values of the input fields get refreshed under a certain circumstance, even though I don't intend it.

For example, when I give a file input first and then fill in the rest of the text fields, all the fields get properly filled in and the inputs are properly sent via `axios.post`, and handled on the back-end side without a problem.

However, when I fill in the text fileds first and then choose a file input, the text fields get refreshed as empty strings and even the file field gets refreshed as `"foo.txt"`.

The below is how the component looks like.

```
import React from 'react';
import Word from '../interfaces/Word.interface';
import WordsDataService from '../api/WordsDataService';
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik'; 
import IWordProps from '../interfaces/IWordProps.interface';
import IWordState from '../interfaces/IWordState.interface';

class CreateWord extends React.Component<IWordProps, IWordState>{

  constructor(props: IWordProps){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      wordId: this.props.match.params.id,
      wordData: {
        id: 0,
        ownLangWordName: '',
        targetLangWordName: '',
        ownLangExSentence: '',
        targetLangExSentence: '',
        createdDate: new Date,
        image: new File(["foo"], "foo.txt")
      }
    }

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.awaitSetState = this.awaitSetState.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    // directly mutating the state. to be refined later 
    this.state.wordData.id = null; 
  }

  async awaitSetState(stateUpdate: Word){
    await this.setState({wordData : stateUpdate})
  }

  onChange(e: { currentTarget: HTMLInputElement; }){
    const chosenFile = e.currentTarget.files[0];
    console.log("The value of chosenFile:");
    console.log(chosenFile);

    let tempWordData = this.state.wordData;
    tempWordData.image = chosenFile;  

    this.awaitSetState(tempWordData);
    console.log("The value of this.state.wordData: ");
    console.log(this.state.wordData);
  }  

  onSubmit(values: Word){
    let word = values;

    WordsDataService.createWord(word)
    .then(() => this.props.history.push('/'))       
  }
  
  render(){
    let { id, ownLangWordName, 
      targetLangWordName, ownLangExSentence, 
      targetLangExSentence, createdDate, 
      image} 
      = this.state.wordData; 

    return(
      <div>
        <h2>Create Word</h2>
        <div>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{ id, ownLangWordName, 
              targetLangWordName, ownLangExSentence, 
              targetLangExSentence, createdDate, 
              image}}
            onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
            enableReinitialize={true}
          >
            {
              (props) => (
                <Form>
                  <fieldset>
                    <label>Word (Target Language)</label>&nbsp;
                    <Field type="text" name="targetLangWordName"/>
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset>
                    <label>Word (Own Language)</label>&nbsp;
                    <Field type="text" name="ownLangWordName"/>
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset>
                    <label>Sentence (Target Language)</label>&nbsp;
                    <Field type="text" size="75" name="targetLangExSentence"/>
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset>
                    <label>Sentence (Own Language)</label>&nbsp;
                    <Field type="text" size="75" name="ownLangExSentence"/>
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset>
                    <label>Date</label>&nbsp;
                    <Field type="text" name="createdDate"/>
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset>
                    <label>Image</label>&nbsp;
                    <input id="image" type="file" name="image" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                  </fieldset>
                  <button type="submit">Save</button>
                </Form>
              )
            }      
          </Formik>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CreateWord;
```

I know that the empty strings and `"foo.txt"` come from the default values that I give to the `state.wordData` in the code above, but the question is, why does giving an image input after text inputs screw things up, whereas it goes fine when an image input is given first?

I'm aware that I need to be care of about asynchronous features when writing code in JavaScript or TypeScript, but I don't understand why this is still hapenning even after I defined `async & await` method like below and using it.

```
async awaitSetState(stateUpdate: Word){
    await this.setState({wordData : stateUpdate})
}
```